# SQL COUNT and subquery in it

Tags: sql

I have a problem with writing the following query:
Find the names of the battles in which at least 3 ships with number of guns lower than 9 and at least 2 of them have result 'ok' in the battle take part.

[image]

This is the relations of tables and I think the query should be something like this:

```
 select o.BATTLE 
 from OUTCOMES o 
 join SHIPS s on o.SHIP = s.NAME
 join CLASSES c on s.CLASS = c.CLASS
 group by o.BATTLE
 having COUNT(case when 
            -- condition for ar least 3 ships with NUMGUNS < 9 and at least 2 of them with result = 'ok'
            then 1 else null end);
```

I am relatively new in SQL and this is not easy query for me.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I use MSSQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry because english isnt my first lenguaje... but by `at least 2 of them` you mean at least 2 of the `3 with < 9 guns` or 2 from the whole battle?

Comment: @Juan It is a little ambiguous in English. The most likely reading to me is 2 of the 3+.

Comment: @Juan, I mean exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select o.BATTLE 
from OUTCOMES o 
join SHIPS s on o.SHIP = s.NAME
join CLASSES c on s.CLASS = c.CLASS
group by o.BATTLE    
having 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN c.NUMGUNS < 9 THEN 1 END) >= 3
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN o.RESULT = 'OK' THEN 1 END) >= 2
```

You can add `ELSE NULL` for readbilty, but `NULL` is the default value for `CASE`.

Because your question isnt clear you also may consider this one

```
having 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN  c.NUMGUNS < 9 THEN 1 END) >= 3
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.NUMGUNS < 9 AND o.RESULT = 'OK') THEN 1 END) >= 2
```

**EDIT** as suggested by shawnt00

```
select o.BATTLE 
from OUTCOMES o 
join SHIPS s on o.SHIP = s.NAME
join CLASSES c on s.CLASS = c.CLASS
WHERE c.NUMGUNS < 9
group by o.BATTLE    
having 
      COUNT(*) >= 3
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN o.RESULT = 'OK' THEN 1 END) >= 2
```

Comment: @FuzzyTree yes, i was reading that part again. Was to ask for clarification

Comment: I think the second version is a better match.

Comment: btw, you still need join with battle to get the `battle name`

Comment: Of course for the second case the `< 9` condition can be pushed up into the `where` clause resulting in `count(*) >= 3`.

Comment: @shawnt00 You are right, but we still waiting to OP specify query intent.

Comment: @Juan I know how frustrating it is to cover all the bases!

Comment: Thank you, Juan!
That was I was looking for :
`having 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN  c.NUMGUNS < 9 THEN 1 END) >= 3
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN (c.NUMGUNS < 9 AND o.RESULT = 'OK') THEN 1 END) >= 2` .
Actually it is not hard at all, but it was late when I post that, maybe because of that I was thinking that it is hard.

Answer (score 0):

without sample data and your expected outcome, it is hard to guess exactly the logic you would like imposed, but here is my best guess:

```
 select o.BATTLE 
 from OUTCOMES o 
 join SHIPS s on o.SHIP = s.NAME
 join CLASSES c on s.CLASS = c.CLASS
 group by o.BATTLE
 having COUNT(case when c.numguns<9 then 1 else null end)>=3 
    and COUNT(case when o.result='ok' then 1 else null end)>=2;
```